# $e^{1/x} \sim 1/(1-e^{-x})$ as $x \to +0$

Tags: calculus

I saw that $e^{1/x} \sim 1/(1-e^{-x})$ as $x \to 0^+$, i.e.

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}e^{1/x}(1-e^{-x})=1$$

But why is it true?I tried L'hospital but it seems not good.

Comment: By $x\to+0$, do you mean $ \lim_{x \to 0^+} $?

Comment: @AhaanRungta Yes.

Comment: Great! Edited. What have you tried?

Comment: Why was my edit rollbacked?

Comment: @AhaanRungta I think your expression was awkward, and I edited it.

Comment: L'Hopital works for two-sided limits, do you have one here?

Comment: @Gobi How was it awkward? Anyway, made it nicer.

Comment: @AhaanRungta You wrote $\lim f(x) \sim \lim g(x)$. But the symbol $\sim$ I wrote has meanings on functions and the behavior as $x$ approaches to a point.

Comment: @Gobi Ah, good you corrected it, thanks! :)

Comment: Just by curiosity, where did you find that $e^{1/x} \sim 1/(1-e^{-x})$ as $x \to +0$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I think it was a typo in http://math.stanford.edu/~rhoades/FILES/solutionsCA.pdf p.25 #6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true.  As $x \to 0^+$, we have $1-e^{-x} \sim x $.  Now is $e^{1/x} \sim \frac1x$?  This is the same as showing $y \sim e^y$ as $y \to +\infty$.  L'Hopital shows that $\frac{e^y}y \to \infty$ as $y \to +\infty$, and so this is clearly false.

Answer (score 2):

Take logs (which you can do when $x>0$) and see what happens.